# Make Android App available only for Work Profile on Playstore

Tags: android, authentication, google-play

I have developed an app for my college using which the students can start receiving job posts notifications. I want to make it available only for work profiles so that people can access it only using the university email id.

It would be great if someone could guide me regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: why you don't giving the validation while taking input of email address.?, User can only login when email host name end with university domain.

Comment: @MahendraGohil but wouldn't that be a bad user experience? Suppose I downloaded the app from my normal profile and not the work profile, then the user would simply be unable to login to the app and not understand what is going on. Even if I do add instructions there, they would have to reinstall the app from the work profile. Instead of this, can't we just make the app available for work profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this document for more details.
https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles

Comment: This does not answer my question. I have a quite specific need and hence have asked this over here.